# Showing Measurability of empirical process (with respect to ball measurability)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm currently working on a problem in a certain proof which i do not fully comprehend, so i'm asking here to hopefully get some help for understanding :-)

The situation of the problem is the following:

$X:\Omega\rightarrow D(\mathbb{R}^2_{+})$  is a stochastic process which is locally uniformly bounded on every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2_{+}$ with $D(\mathbb{R}^2_{+})$ denoting the space of cadlag functions (left side limits exist, right continuous) over $\mathbb{R}^2_{+}$. It can be shown that $X$ ist measurable with respect to the ball-$\sigma$-field on $D(\mathbb{R}^2_{+})$ but not the corresponding Borel-$\sigma-$field (with underlying uniform metric).

Well so far so good, problem is now the following expression:

$P\left( \underset{\substack{|x_{1}-x_{2}|^2+|y_{1}-y_{2}|^2<\delta \\ x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2}\in[0,1]}}{\sup} \left|X(x_{1},y_{1})-X(x_{2},y_{2})  \right|  \geq \varepsilon    \right)$   for arbitrary $\delta,\varepsilon>0$.

Why is it possible to take probability here? How can we conclude measurability for this expression from the above stated ball measurability? My problem ist that i cannot draw the connection from the space of cadlag functions to this expression which somewhat looks more like coordinate projections...somewhere you have to fit in the ball measurability but i cannot find a reasonable answer and would therefore be really grateful for helpful input :-)

*Edit: If you need further information, the above mentioned problematic expression can be found in the following paper:
http://www.lse.ac.uk/statistics/documents/researchreport101.pdf at the bottom of page 9/ top of page 10. As mentioned above i cannot fully comprehend the conclusion which is drawn out of the ball measurability.*

*Edit 2: To be even more precise, is there any possibility to write the above expression as*

$P\left( X \in K_{\varepsilon,\delta}   \right)$

*where $K_{\varepsilon,\delta}$ lies in the ball-$\sigma-$field of $D(\mathbb{R}^2_{+})$?*